# ConnectWise Rest API

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

I am really struggling with the initial step for authenticating my rest call to connectwise rest API. The support is not up for help.

I am using PHP with curl for using their API. I am sure there is something that I am missing out. Can someone please help with this?

```
$curl = curl_init();
$usertype='x-cw-usertype: integrator';

       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);

       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-staging.connectwisedev.com" . "/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/services/tickets/420");

       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(

                 'Authorization: basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password),

                 $usertype,

 'Content-type: application/json'

           ));


$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump($result);
```

Here `$username = "companyID"."+"."username"`
and `$password = "password"`

All, companyID, username and password are provided by the company when you get you staging demo setup.

In the response I always get NULL. I have seen people reporting the errors they get generally for authentication, however, I never receive anything even if I change anything. Am I missing something very crucial?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: i dont know why you get NULL, but turn off RETURNTRANSFER, and enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE, and you should see a much more detailed log of what's going on, and what's going wrong, in the request

Comment: @hanshenrik Thanks for your reply, I tried that. I am sure I am making some big blunder here, Still not getting anything on the screen. When we turn on the VERBOSE will it give the result in $result = curl_exec(...) ? I mean if I var_dump $result, I should be getting something as trace of error isn't it?

Comment: var_dump(curl_exec($ch)) just dumps what curl_exec() returned. but yeah, it is redirected to php's stderr. you can redirect it to something else by doing $fp=fopen('curl_stderr.log','ab');curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_STDERR,$fp);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);

then you get the log in curl_stderr.log  file.

Comment: Thank you for your help, well I was not very clear with the process of interacting with connectwise. I got it working. For others who are confused. make sure you have right public and private keys, and correct auth. We do not need ssl_verifypeer. I cannot belive it was so easy. Now I feel like I am stupid. :D

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue just putting my client ID now works for me.

```
  $curl = curl_init();
   $usertype='x-cw-usertype: integrator';
   $username = "xxxxx";
   $password = "xxxxx";


   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-eu.myconnectwise.net/v2020_3/apis/3.0" . "/finance/accounting/unpostedinvoices");

   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Authorization: basic ' . base64_encode($username.':'.$password), 
   'clientId: '. 'xxxxx',$usertype, 
   'Content-type: application/json'));

   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   print_r($result);
   curl_close($curl);
```